# how to display the end and start time android countdowntimer

Tags: java, android, timer, countdown, countdowntimer

when i run the code below i can not display the start and the end time like 00:00:00 every time the timer start, in the future i want to let the user define how many countdown timer he need and time for each one with repeat on them so any assist for display is vital and if someone can improve the code for the next step i will very appreciate that.
Thank for the assist,

```
repeterTimer = new CountDownTimer(3000, 1000) {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

            isRunning = true;
            meditiongong.setLooping(false);
            long millis = millisUntilFinished;  
             String hms = String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis),  
                 TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis) - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis)),  
                 TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millis) - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis))); 
             textViewTimer.setText(hms);

        }
        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            textViewTimer.setText("00:00:00");
            isRunning = false;
            meditiongong.start();
            if (repeater) {
                numRepeat ++ ;
                numOfRepeat.setText("" + numRepeat);
                repeterTimer.start();
            } else {
                meditiongong.setLooping(true);
            }

        }
    };

}
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need a TextView where the values from timer will be displayed. 
I have an example of a countdown timer with value display:

```
private TextView remainingTimeDisplay;
private int timerProgressStatus;


remainingTimeDisplay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.remainingTimeDisplay);


private void setQuizTimer(int time) {
    final int actualTime = time*1000;
    CountDownTimer gameCountDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(actualTime, 1000) {
        int totalTime = actualTime;
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

            /*Display time left in a textview*/
            long millis =String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis),  
             TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis) - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis)),  
             TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millis) - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis)));
            remainingTimeDisplay.setText(hms);

            /*Progress bar display values*/
            timerProgressStatus = (int)(( totalTime - millisUntilFinished ) /(double)totalTime * 100);
            timerProgressBar.setProgress(timerProgressStatus);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            Toast.makeText(QuestionActivity.this,"Countdown Ended",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }.start();
}
```

When you want to use this method you only need to call the it with the number of secounds.
Ex: For 10 secounds setQuizTimer(10);
The output will be 09:59, hope this helps.

Comment: For 00:00:00 you need just to add %02d:%02d%02d and another TimerUnit below. Cheers

Comment: what you mean by "and another TimerUnit below", i can see the time from 2 sec and 1 sec but 3 and 0 when the timer on repeater i can't see

Comment: @itayfriedman I edited the response, now you have hour/minutes/secounds. This is a complete and functional android countdown timer. Cheers

Comment: as you see i have textview where the value display if the timer not repeat everything is go fine i can see the start time and at the end i see the zero time but when the timer repeat i could not see the zero time and the start time why ?